# Xcode IOS Connect to a specific wireless network using SSID and Password

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, wifi, ssid

I'm currently creating an iPhone app (Xcode 4.3.1, IOS 5) that has to work with wi-fi routers! Main goal of this application is indoor navigation (GPS inside buildings isn't really accurate).

One solution could be to scan all available wi-fi and then my application could make it's job! But as far as I looked into all documentations and dozens of articles, Apple doesn't provide any API to scan available wireless networks (actually there are some ways to get around this problem, but if you use them your app will be rejected from AppStore)..

Second solution could be just to connect to specific wi-fi access points!
All these access points are pre-written inside code, something like:
SSID: myHomeWifi; Password: somePassword; ... etc.

My app could try to connect or at least access or ping each of these routers and then make calculations.

So the question is.. is there any way to make connection with some wifi access point if I have all private data of the router?

any advice would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: I don't believe Apple exposes any APIs for controlling the network interface.

Comment: and what about bluetooth? is there any way to get list of ALL available devices (not only ipads, iphones, or ipods) ?

Comment: were you able to do it?

Comment: Please reply. I also want to do same kind of thing. If you are able to do it then please reply.